# Classifying singular points of an ordinary linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following linear ODE homogeneous

$$ y^{(n)}(x) + p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}(x) + ... + p_1(x)y'(x) + p_0(x)y(x)=0  $$

To classify the point $x= \infty$ as ordinary or regular singular point, usually, the trick is to use $x = \frac{1}{t}$ since $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} = \infty $. Is there any other transformation we can use??

For example, Im thinking of $x = \frac{1}{t^n}$  since $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1}{t^n} = \infty$.

In general, can we just choose any $f(t)$ such that $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t) = \infty$ and put $x= f(t)$ and then this would help us classify the point at infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think about this equation as equation on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{CP}^1$ (it is also 1-dimensional projective space, this is why I use this notation). Any holomorphic automorphism of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ can be used for your problem. Moreover, holomorphic automorphisms of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are well known: they form group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ that acts on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by fractional-linear transformations $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Such fractional-linear transformation maps $\infty$ to $\frac{a}{c}$, hence you can map $\infty$ to any point you want on the complex plane.

Map $x = \frac{1}{t^n}$ is not $1:1$ and this complicates computations drastically.

Comment: so, this means or example, that I cant use $x= \frac{1}{\sinh t } $?

Comment: It looks like you worry about only one point at infinity. But there are other singular points and you need to analyze them after change of variable. In you example you will need to analyze poles of $p_i(\frac{1}{\sinh t })$ and $\frac{1}{\sinh t }$ has infinitely many poles.

Comment: The point is to move infinity to a finite point and don't introduce any new additional zeroes or poles for other coefficients, this is way you need holomorphic automorphism.